# Python Selenium WebDriverWait doesn't work but find_element_by_name does

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
try:
#        search = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
#            EC.presence_of_element_located(By.NAME, "email")
#        )
    search = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
except:
    print("Did not find ID email")
```

The code commented out throws an exception but the other code works.  They both do the same this except I want to make sure the element is there before I doing anything else.
Why does WebDriverWait fail?

Comment: presence_of_element_located instead of this use visibility or element to be clickabke condition and then it would work

Comment: I am using presence_of_element_located in the code that is commented out.  That is what I am trying to get to work.

Comment: Well if that does not work, wouldn't you try something which has more meaning in Selenium ?

Comment: "The code commented out throws an exception"... you didn't post the exception so we can't guess what that might be. Post the full exception, properly formatted, and maybe we can help you.

Comment: Also, presence just means that the element exists in the DOM, not that it in interactable, etc. If you try to `click()` or `send_keys()` to an element that is present but not visible, you will get an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a parentheses, the correct code would be:

```
search = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "email"))
)
```

This is because presence_of_element_located expects a locator and you need an extra parentheses to By.NAME and "email" be evaluated as a locator, otherwise they would be passed as two parameters.

Comment: You are wise sir.  That did the trick.